# Changing the response status code when using rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

I am building a rails api server with `rabl` as the json responder. For all the success methods, rabl's default status code is `200` but we have some internally assigned status codes for different scenario. Is there a way to change the status code when sending the response?

Comment: Are you sure that RABL (i.e. the templating system) is sending the status code? This should be handled by your controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you render your view with `respond_with` or `render` methods, you could write:

```
render @something, status: 400

respond_with @smething, status: 400
```

`rabl` - just templating system for rendering resources